# cancelConnect() not working in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to close the connection after sending a file through WiFi Direct. I pass the manager and channel to the AsyncTask(Which deals with crating Socket) and call cancelConnect() on them at the end of doInBackground(). It is unable to close the connection but when i call cancelConnect() in MainActivity it works fine. Why is this so?

```
package com.ex.bb;


public class SocketAsync extends AsyncTask<Wrapper,Object,Object> {

private Context context;
 //   private TextView statusText;

    public SocketAsync(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
protected String doInBackground(Wrapper...w) {

    //File Sending Code
     w[0].manager.cancelConnect(w[0].channel,new ActionListener(){
        @Override 
        public void onSuccess() { 
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Disconnected from device");
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Couldn't disconnect from device");
        } 
    }); 


}
```

Wrapper class consists of manager and channel.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing cancelConnect() in doInBackground, do in onPostExecute()